# Applescript / Finder select specific items in a folder including those in disclosed subfolders by file name or file path list

Tags: applescript, finder

Here's our situation:

We have a list of file names and/or full file paths (we can generate either)

The files in our list are all contained under one folder, but scattered across multiple sub-folders. (There are hundreds of items in our select list from thousands of possible files.  Selecting manually isn't an option)

We've got the root folder open in list view and all sub-folders, sub-sub etc disclosure-opened (btw thanks to http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030218164922494 for the shortcut "*command, option, control and shift when pressing the right arrow*")

With all files visible under one window open we want to automatically select all the items in our file list so that they can then be dragged at once to an application.

Comment: If you can generate a list of fully qualified pathnames of the target files to be opened, then IMO selecting them in Finder to then drag and drop to an application **is not the way to go!** Use the list and script it to have the application open the files from the list instead. Or any method that can iterate the list to open the files in a given application.

Comment: So this particular app (Avid, btw) pops up a dialogue box for each import and then takes anywhere from 1 minute to 60 minutes to transcode each imported file.  It can't import from a list, nor be scripted to import, wait for transcode to finish, import next, etc.  By contrast, drag-and-dropping a selection of files will pop up the dialogue once and import all the subsequent files one after another.

Answer (score 0):

This works using the latest version of Sierra.

I was not able to figure out a way to selectively select files in folders with subfolders with subfolders etc.  The only solution I was able to come up with was to create folder called “Aliases”  and have AppleScript create alias files to all of the ”selected files” and store all of the aliases in the aliases folder.  From there you can drag all of the files and drop them into your application as you desired

If you have a plain text file containing POSIX path filenames, each on a separate line like the example in this next image, this version will load the pathnames from the text file directly into the script. Just save this script as an application.  You can drag text files directly onto the icon of the app because the code is set up to be a droplet

[image]

```
global theFile
property theInfo : missing value
property theName : missing value
property theList : {}
property theList2 : {}
property aliasFolder : (path to desktop as text) & "Aliases"

on open theFiles
    set theInfo to info for theFiles
    set theName to POSIX path of theFiles

    getLinesofFileAsList(theName)

    tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists of alias aliasFolder) then
            make new folder at (path to desktop as text) with properties {name:"Aliases"}
        end if
        delete every item of alias aliasFolder
    end tell

    repeat with i from 1 to count of theList
        try
            set theResult to POSIX file (item i of theList) as text
            set end of theList2 to theResult
            tell application "Finder"
                set theAliases to make new alias file at aliasFolder to theResult
            end tell
        end try
    end repeat

    delay 0.5

    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        delay 0.5
        set hmmm to reveal aliasFolder
        delay 0.5
        set hmmm to select every item of alias aliasFolder
        activate hmmm
    end tell
end open

on getLinesofFileAsList(theName)
    set theFile to theName
    set theFile to POSIX path of theName
    set theList to read POSIX file theFile as text
    set saveTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
    set theList to paragraphs of theList
    if last item of theList is "" then
        set theList to reverse of rest of reverse of theList
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveTID
end getLinesofFileAsList


--on run
--  --  Handle the case where the script is launched without any dropped files
--end run
```

[image]

Comment: What practical purpose does `property theList2 : {}` and `set end of theList2 to theResult` serve? None that I can see, you're creating a list property and populating that list and then doing absolutely nothing with it! What practical purpose does the `if not (exists of alias aliasFolder) then` block serve within the `repeat` _loop_? It does not belong within the `repeat` _loop_ as it's going to needlessly check hundreds of times as the OP stated "There are hundreds of items in our select list from thousands of possible files"!

Comment: While I have in the past created a set of aliases to a files stored in different locations to act upon for a given process, nonetheless I'll give you the credit for posting it first in this answer! Honorary +1 However I felt your code had enough other issues that I had to post my own answer.

Comment: I am assuming the original input list (theList) of full file paths to be “selected” in a Finder window, would be in the Posix path format.  The purpose of creating the “theList2” variable is to convert the Posix path formated items from the original list to HFS formated items into that new list, at which point Finder process the items from “theList2”

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that with *basic* **AppleScript** one can programmatically select multiple items in **Finder** which span throughout different *folders* and *subfolders* within a given *folder* in one *window*. Maybe with **Cocoa-AppleScript**, don't know, however if **Avid** can open *files* from **file aliases**, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is a viable option.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* makes the following assumptions:

- There is a *plain text file* containing the *fully qualified POSIX pathnames* of the *target files* to be processed with **Avid** and the *name* of the *file* is: **List of Files to Process with Avid.txt**
- The *name* of the *folder* containing the *aliases* is: **Aliases of Files to Process with Avid**
- The **Desktop** is used as the *location* in the *filesystem* that the aforementioned *file* and *folder* exists, to be processed by **Avid**.

Obviously these settings can be changed as needed/wanted, see the comments in the *code*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
--  # Set the value of the following three property variables:
--  #
--  # The value of 'thisLocation' is an colon-delimited path string, e.g. 'path to desktop as string' returns: "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:"
--  # NOTE: When not using 'path to (folder)' where 'folder' is a 'folder constant' , the special folder for which to return the path, the value should be in the form of an colon-delimited path string.
--  # See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19
--  #
--  # The value of 'theListFilename' is the name of the plain text file containing the fully quilified pathnames of the target files to be opened in Avid.
--  # The value of 'theFolderName' is the name of the temporary folder the temporary aliases will be created in. This folder gets created new each run with new aliases.
--  #
--  # NOTE: For ease of use, as each run is presumed to be temporary to get that job run done, the location of the 'theListFilename' and 'theFolderName' are both in 'thisLocation'.

property thisLocation : (path to desktop as string)
property theListFilename : "List of Files to Process with Avid.txt"
property theFolderName : "Aliases of Files to Process with Avid"

--  # The remaining code is tokenized and should not need to be modified.

tell application "Finder"
    if (exists thisLocation & theListFilename) then
        tell current application to set theList to read alias (thisLocation & theListFilename)
    else
        display dialog "The file, \"" & theListFilename & "\", was not found at the expected location." buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Missing File" with icon 0
        return
    end if
    set theFolderPathname to thisLocation & theFolderName
    if not (exists theFolderPathname) then
        make new folder at thisLocation with properties {name:theFolderName}
    else
        move theFolderPathname to trash
        make new folder at thisLocation with properties {name:theFolderName}
    end if
    repeat with i from 1 to length of theList
        try
            make new alias file at theFolderPathname to POSIX file (paragraph i of theList)
        end try
    end repeat
    reveal theFolderPathname
    activate
    -- delay 1 --   # In necessary, uncomment and adjust value as appropriate.
    select every item of alias theFolderPathname
end tell
```

In **Script Editor**, save this *script* and an *application*, e.g. **Select Files to Process with Avid**, and then run as needed after replacing the e.g. **List of Files to Process with Avid.txt** with the current set of *target files* to be processed with **Avid**.

The *script* does the following:

- Checks to see the *file* e.g. **List of Files to Process with Avid.txt** exists and if not displays error message and exits.
- Checks to see if the *folder* e.g. **Aliases of Files to Process with Avid** exist and if not creates it, and if it exists, moves it to the **Trash** and creates it anew, for the new run of *target files* to be processed.
- Creates an *alias* of each *file* listed, as a *fully qualified POSIX pathname*, in the *file* e.g.:
   **List of Files to Process with Avid.txt**
- Opens the *folder*, e.g. **Select Files to Process with Avid**, in **Finder** and selects the *aliases*.

You are now ready to drag and drop the selected *aliases* to **Avid**.

<sub>Note: This script assumes the fully qualified POSIX pathnames of the target files to be processes with Avid do not contain linefeeds, carriage returns and or null characters in their pathnames.</sub>

Comment: Thank you user3439894.  The only fly in the ointment is that Avid does not, in fact, recognize aliases as pointers, but rather as media which it haplessly attempts to import.  What we did work out instead was unix Hard Links, which, with a little bit of NodeJS and CLI are both easy to create and machine-recognizeable.  In some ways the Alias approach would have actually been better because it would have communicated the original file paths rather than the new ones.  Thanks again.